# Como fazer um texto ser editado apenas uma vez em JavaScript/Html

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    function saveImg() {
        let out = [];
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
        const fav = document.getElementById("favourites");
        out.push(`<div>`);
        out.push(`<img src= ${imgData} height = "200" alt = "image">`);
        out.push(`<form action="/favorites" method="POST">`);
        out.push(`<input type="hidden" value=${imgData} name="dataURL">`);
        out.push(`<input type="hidden" value=${id++} name="_id">`);
        out.push(`<input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name" readonly>`);
        out.push(`<label for="name"></label>`);
        out.push(`<br>`);
        out.push(`<input type="submit"  value="SUBMIT">`);
        out.push(`</form>`);
        out.push(`</div>`);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        history.clear();
        fav.innerHTML += out.join("");
    }
```

Nesse código a pessoa pode apertar um botão para salvar um desenho feito num canvas, e então dar um nome a imagem salva, no entanto, após escrever o nome eu queria fazer com que o input se tornasse `"readonly"`. Que alternativas existem para esse efeito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem 2 formas de desabilitar um input:

1. Alterar o atributo `disabled` para `true` que vai esmaecer o input **impedindo a interação**, mas também impede que ele seja modificado.
2. Alterar o atributo `readOnly` para `true`, **permitindo a interação** com o input, mas também impede que o conteúdo seja modificado.

Aqui usei um botão genérico que ao clicar, chama uma função javascript, mas você pode usar a função `disableInput` em qualquer lugar:

```html
<input type="text" id="imageName"/>
<button type="button" onClick="disableInput()">Salvar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const disableInput = () => {
      const imageNameInput = document.querySelector('#imageName')
      imageNameInput.disabled = true
      // Se preferir, pode optar pelo atributo 'readOnly' para evitar esmaecer o input
      // imageNameInput.readOnly = true
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Desabilitar o input funciona pra você?

```js
function disable() {
  document.getElementById("myText").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

Input: <input type="text" id="myText">

<p>Clique no botão para desabilitar.</p>

<button onclick="disable()">Desabilitar input</button>

</body>
</html>
```